# VLC on WindowForm

Tags: c#, vlc, libvlc

Im using VLC on Windows Form, coding in C# under VS 2017. I installed the 4 plugins through nuGet, added vlcControl1 to the form, set the vlcLibDirectory and, on form loads, I wrote:

```
vlcControl1.SetMedia(curFolder + @"\media\1.mp4");
vlcControl1.Play();
```

Even if I have no error, no file is displayed. The path to file is ok, but I don't know if the way to add it is right.

Comment: VLC or VLS? You say both.

Comment: @itsme86 VLC. Sorry for the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide the full [MRL](https://wiki.videolan.org/Media_resource_locator/) which requires the `file:///` prefix in this case.

```
vlcControl1.SetMedia("file:///" + curFolder + @"\media\1.mp4");
```

Or you could just convert to a `FileInfo` object instead:

```
vlcControl1.SetMedia(new FileInfo(curFolder + @"\media\1.mp4"));
vlcControl1.Play();
```

You could also just overload the `play()` call:

```
vlcControl1.Play(new FileInfo(curFolder + @"\media\1.mp4"));
```

---

Also: if you're using Win Forms you only need 3 plugins, you can exclude `Vlc.DotNet.Wpf`